# how do i load a function after results from google custom search finish loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-app-engine, google-custom-search

I need to load a function after each search query completes. so far, I've tried `setOnloadCallback` and `google.load('search', '1',callBack:function(){});`but they only load once! When the search page initializes, any idea how to run a function after each search query?

This is what i tried before, (callback executes only once!):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load('search', '1');


function onLoad() {

    alert("done"); // alert only loads once!

    var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl(
        "005940701165615368768:xubh5v9fsum");

    var drawOptions = new google.search.DrawOptions();
    drawOptions.setSearchFormRoot('search-form');

    customSearchControl.draw('results', drawOptions);
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is what worked for me, `customSearchControl.setSearchCompleteCallback(this,function(){ alert("search completed");});`

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is incorrect.  The third parameter of `.load()` should be a dict:

`google.load("search", "1", {"callback" : onLoadCallback});`

Also, check that you don't camelcase `callBack`.  It should be `callback`.